# Requests send double backslash instead of single

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I requested a site using `requests.get()`. Cookies is now in `r.cookies`.
Than I sent my request to server, but the server throw me 400 error.

When I looked closer in debug log, I saw, that it sent the cookies (`=r.cookies`) with double backslashes. But when I print it using `print(r.cookies)` or `print(r.cookies[cookieName])`, it prints with only single backslash.
I know that I need single backslash, because Google Chrome debug tool says, that the page sends it.

Google Chrome sends single backslash.

[image]

Source code:

```
import requests
import time
import json
import math
import random

import logging
try:
    import http.client as http_client
except ImportError:
    # Python 2
    import httplib as http_client
http_client.HTTPConnection.debuglevel = 1

logging.basicConfig()
logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log = logging.getLogger("requests.packages.urllib3")
requests_log.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
requests_log.propagate = True

def _base36encode(integer):
    chars, encoded = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz', ''
    while integer > 0:
        integer, remainder = divmod(integer, 36)
        encoded = chars[remainder] + encoded
    return encoded

def _register(firstName, lastName, email, password, captchaApiKey):
    startTime = int(1e3 * time.time())

    url = 'https://www.quora.com'
    httpsProxy = 'https://207.99.118.74:8080'
    proxy = {"https" : httpsProxy}
    headers = {'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language':'cs-CZ,cs;q=0.8,en;q=0.6','Cache-Control':'max-age=0','Connection':'keep-alive','Host':'www.quora.com','Upgrade-Insecure-Requests':'1','User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36'}
    r = requests.get(url, headers=headers, proxies=proxy)
    quoraHtml = r.text
    data = {}
    data['proxy'] = proxy
    data['cookies'] = r.cookies
    print (data['cookies'])
    ######################
    ## get certification tokens ##
    #####################
    pos1 = quoraHtml.find('"formkey": "')
    pos2 = quoraHtml.find('"', pos1+13)
    data['formKey'] = quoraHtml[pos1+12:pos2] #form key for certification
    pos1 = quoraHtml.find('"postkey": "', pos2)
    pos2 = quoraHtml.find('"', pos1+13)
    data['postKey'] = quoraHtml[pos1+12:pos2] #form key for certification

    pos1 = quoraHtml.find('"serverCallUrl": "/')
    pos2 = quoraHtml.find('"', pos1+19)
    data['sendUrl'] = 'https://www.quora.com' + quoraHtml[pos1+18:pos2] #url to send data

    pos1 = quoraHtml.find('"windowId": "', pos2)
    pos2 = quoraHtml.find('"', pos1+14)
    data['windowId'] = quoraHtml[pos1+13:pos2] #form key for certification

    pos1 = quoraHtml.find('"SignupValidator", "', pos2)
    pos2 = quoraHtml.find('"', pos1+21)
    firstNameValidateEncrypted = quoraHtml[pos1+20:pos2] #encrypted first name validator
    pos1 = quoraHtml.find('"SignupValidator", "', pos2)
    pos2 = quoraHtml.find('"', pos1+21)
    lastNameValidateEncrypted = quoraHtml[pos1+20:pos2] #encrypted last name validator
    pos1 = quoraHtml.find('"SignupValidator", "', pos2)
    pos2 = quoraHtml.find('"', pos1+21)
    mailValidateEncrypted = quoraHtml[pos1+20:pos2] #encrypted email validator
    pos1 = quoraHtml.find('"SignupValidator", "', pos2)
    pos2 = quoraHtml.find('"', pos1+21)
    passValidateEncrypted = quoraHtml[pos1+20:pos2] #encrypted password validator

    pos1 = quoraHtml.find('"hmacs": {')
    pos2 = quoraHtml.find('}', pos1+11)
    formDecryptKeyListText = quoraHtml[pos1+9:pos2+1] #decryption key list in string format
    formDecryptKeyList = json.loads(formDecryptKeyListText) #decryption key list

    data['firstNameValidate'] = formDecryptKeyList[firstNameValidateEncrypted]
    data['lastNameValidate'] = formDecryptKeyList[lastNameValidateEncrypted]
    data['mailValidate'] = formDecryptKeyList[mailValidateEncrypted]
    data['passValidate'] = formDecryptKeyList[passValidateEncrypted]

    data['e2e'] = _base36encode(int(1e3 * startTime + math.floor(1e3 * random.random())))

    ##############
    ## validate data ##
    ##############
    _validate('first_name',firstName,data)

def _validate(validate,value,formData):
    data = {}
    data['json'] = '{"args":[],"kwargs":{"value":"'+value+'"}}'
    data['formKey'] = formData['formKey']
    data['postKey'] = formData['postKey']
    data['window_id'] = formData['windowId']
    data['referring_controller'] = 'index'
    data['referring_action'] = 'index'
    if validate == 'first_name':
        data['__vcon_json'] = '["'+formData['firstNameValidate']+'"]'
    elif validate == 'last_name':
        data['__vcon_json'] = '["'+formData['lastNameValidator']+'"]'
    elif validate == 'email':
        data['__vcon_json'] = '["'+formData['mailValidator']+'"]'
    elif validate == 'password':
        data['__vcon_json'] = '["'+formData['passValidator']+'"]'
    data['__vcon_method'] = 'validate'
    data['__e2e_action_id'] = formData['e2e']
    data['js_init'] = '{"id":"@'+validate+'"}'
    data['__metadata'] = '{}'
    headers = {'Accept': 'application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01', 'Accept-Language':'cs-CZ,cs;q=0.8,en;q=0.6','Connection':'keep-alive','Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8','Host':'www.quora.com','Origin':'https://www.quora.com','Referer':'https://www.quora.com/','User-Agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/56.0.2924.87 Safari/537.36','X-Requested-With':'XMLHttpRequest'}
    r = requests.post(formData['sendUrl'], data=data, headers=headers, cookies=formData['cookies'], proxies=formData['proxy'])
    print (r.status_code)


def createAccount(captchaApiKey):
    _register('First','Last','mail@gmail.co','abcd123*',captchaApiKey)

captchaApiKey = 'b6d955900d620d2589c03fef5239a1be'
createAccount(captchaApiKey)
```

Comment: Paste your code please, screenshots isn't recommended here.

Comment: I don't think it is allow to have some antislash in cookies (https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6265.txt). maybe the requests library is trying to help by escaping things... instead of manually retrieving the cookies from the first request, you could try to use requests' Session object: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/. The Session object will automatically store the cookies and pass them to subsequent calls.

Comment: Thanks. Finaly it's working!

Comment: @gamecraftCZ Would you edit this to your question or add as an (accepted) answers, so that others can find this? Currently it is buried in the comments.